# prototype.js and Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'style' is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have the following javascript error - Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'style' is null or not an object. 
I'm using prototype-1.6.1.js library. The error is in the prototpye library code:

```
Element.Methods.getStyle = function(element, style) {
element = $(element);
style = (style == 'float' || style == 'cssFloat') ? 'styleFloat' : style.camelize();
var value = element.style[style];
```

This error happens only on the development machine, on Internet explorer while debugging. I don't have this error on production. In the call stack, I see that the first function is 'function bind(context)' which is a prototype's function. I don't use it anywhere in my code...

Comment: Are you sure you're calling this function on an actual element object?

Comment: I don't think it is actual element (and it seems that this is the problem). I don't call it from my code. bind() function from prototype is raised and it calls 15 others functions and at the end .getStyle boom.

Comment: so what is the input on which it crashes? what are the values of the parameters?